# Mutt silently fails to send an email from the ci/cd pipeline

Tags: ubuntu, email, mutt

Mutt is silently failing to send an email . There are no errors or failures. But sometimes the email is sent while other times it fails to send an email.

This is how I am installing all the required installables/libraries in one task.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install snapd
sudo snap install okular
sudo apt install mailutils
sudo apt install mutt
```

In another task I am sending an email like this:

```
url=https://dev.azure.com/xyz/project/_build/results?buildId=$(Build.BuildId)


echo -e "$url"

mutt -v 

echo -e "Hello All,\n\n Please find inline as well as attached the elaborative test results which $(Agent.JobStatus) and generated  \n\nRegards\nQA Team\n\nLink to Azure DevOps Pipeline Build : $url-- abcd@def.com
```

Following is the log of sending email . I do not see any errors here.

```
2023-06-13T06:34:21.9114531Z ##[section]Starting: Email with E2E report and logs using utils
2023-06-13T06:34:21.9118245Z ==============================================================================
2023-06-13T06:34:21.9118373Z Task         : Bash
2023-06-13T06:34:21.9118437Z Description  : Run a Bash script on macOS, Linux, or Windows
2023-06-13T06:34:21.9118539Z Version      : 3.214.0
2023-06-13T06:34:21.9118605Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2023-06-13T06:34:21.9118684Z Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/bash
2023-06-13T06:34:21.9118799Z ==============================================================================
2023-06-13T06:34:22.0517617Z Generating script.
2023-06-13T06:34:22.0538699Z ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
2023-06-13T06:34:22.0549802Z [command]/usr/bin/bash /home/vsts/work/_temp/8c145d8d-536a-4543-addb-40c24c02f85d.sh
2023-06-13T06:34:22.0625138Z https://dev.azure.com/xyz/project/_build/results?buildId=5209788
2023-06-13T06:34:22.0656911Z Mutt 1.13.2 (2019-12-18)
2023-06-13T06:34:22.0657459Z Copyright (C) 1996-2016 Michael R. Elkins and others.
2023-06-13T06:34:22.0658162Z Mutt comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; for details type `mutt -vv'.
2023-06-13T06:34:22.0658578Z Mutt is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
2023-06-13T06:34:22.0658981Z under certain conditions; type `mutt -vv' for details.
2023-06-13T06:34:22.0659300Z 
2023-06-13T06:34:22.0660934Z System: Linux 5.15.0-1038-azure (x86_64)
2023-06-13T06:34:22.0661328Z ncurses: ncurses 6.2.20200212 (compiled with 6.2)
2023-06-13T06:34:22.0661631Z libidn: 1.33 (compiled with 1.33)
2023-06-13T06:34:22.0734866Z hcache backend: tokyocabinet 1.4.48
2023-06-13T06:34:22.0735064Z 
2023-06-13T06:34:22.0735270Z Compiler:
2023-06-13T06:34:22.0735584Z Using built-in specs.
2023-06-13T06:34:22.0735779Z COLLECT_GCC=gcc
2023-06-13T06:34:22.0736064Z COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/lto-wrapper
2023-06-13T06:34:22.0736360Z OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:hsa
2023-06-13T06:34:22.0736561Z OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
2023-06-13T06:34:22.0736984Z Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
2023-06-13T06:34:22.0738676Z Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-9/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,gm2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-9 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none=/build/gcc-9-Av3uEd/gcc-9-9.4.0/debian/tmp-nvptx/usr,hsa --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
2023-06-13T06:34:22.0739695Z Thread model: posix
2023-06-13T06:34:22.0739956Z gcc version 9.4.0 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 
2023-06-13T06:34:22.0740049Z 
2023-06-13T06:34:22.0741633Z Configure options: '--build=x86_64-linux-gnu' '--prefix=/usr' '--includedir=\${prefix}/include' '--mandir=\${prefix}/share/man' '--infodir=\${prefix}/share/info' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--localstatedir=/var' '--disable-silent-rules' '--libdir=\${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' '--libexecdir=\${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' '--disable-maintainer-mode' '--disable-dependency-tracking' '--with-mailpath=/var/mail' '--enable-compressed' '--enable-debug' '--enable-fcntl' '--enable-hcache' '--enable-gpgme' '--enable-imap' '--enable-smtp' '--enable-pop' '--enable-sidebar' '--enable-nntp' '--enable-dotlock' '--disable-fmemopen' '--with-curses' '--with-gnutls' '--with-gss' '--with-idn' '--with-mixmaster' '--with-sasl' '--without-gdbm' '--without-bdb' '--without-qdbm' '--with-tokyocabinet' 'build_alias=x86_64-linux-gnu' 'CFLAGS=-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/mutt-30uNgF/mutt-1.13.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now' 'CPPFLAGS=-Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2'
2023-06-13T06:34:22.0742559Z 
2023-06-13T06:34:22.0742969Z Compilation CFLAGS: -Wall -pedantic -Wno-long-long -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/mutt-30uNgF/mutt-1.13.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security
2023-06-13T06:34:22.0743153Z 
2023-06-13T06:34:22.0743297Z Compile options:
2023-06-13T06:34:22.0743479Z -DOMAIN
2023-06-13T06:34:22.0743612Z +DEBUG
2023-06-13T06:34:22.0743899Z -HOMESPOOL  +USE_SETGID  +USE_DOTLOCK  +DL_STANDALONE  +USE_FCNTL  -USE_FLOCK   
2023-06-13T06:34:22.0744106Z +USE_POP  +USE_IMAP  +USE_SMTP  
2023-06-13T06:34:22.0744394Z -USE_SSL_OPENSSL  +USE_SSL_GNUTLS  +USE_SASL  +USE_GSS  +HAVE_GETADDRINFO  
2023-06-13T06:34:22.0744658Z +HAVE_REGCOMP  -USE_GNU_REGEX  
2023-06-13T06:34:22.0744866Z +HAVE_COLOR  +HAVE_START_COLOR  +HAVE_TYPEAHEAD  +HAVE_BKGDSET  
2023-06-13T06:34:22.0745086Z +HAVE_CURS_SET  +HAVE_META  +HAVE_RESIZETERM  +HAVE_FUTIMENS  
2023-06-13T06:34:22.0745324Z +CRYPT_BACKEND_CLASSIC_PGP  +CRYPT_BACKEND_CLASSIC_SMIME  +CRYPT_BACKEND_GPGME  
2023-06-13T06:34:22.0745584Z -EXACT_ADDRESS  -SUN_ATTACHMENT  
2023-06-13T06:34:22.0745903Z +ENABLE_NLS  -LOCALES_HACK  +HAVE_WC_FUNCS  +HAVE_LANGINFO_CODESET  +HAVE_LANGINFO_YESEXPR  
2023-06-13T06:34:22.0746252Z +HAVE_ICONV  -ICONV_NONTRANS  +HAVE_LIBIDN  -HAVE_LIBIDN2  +HAVE_GETSID  +USE_HCACHE  
2023-06-13T06:34:22.0746476Z +USE_SIDEBAR  +USE_COMPRESSED  +USE_INOTIFY  
2023-06-13T06:34:22.0746674Z -ISPELL
2023-06-13T06:34:22.0746837Z SENDMAIL="/usr/sbin/sendmail"
2023-06-13T06:34:22.0746993Z MAILPATH="/var/mail"
2023-06-13T06:34:22.0747156Z PKGDATADIR="/usr/share/mutt"
2023-06-13T06:34:22.0747315Z SYSCONFDIR="/etc"
2023-06-13T06:34:22.0747487Z EXECSHELL="/bin/sh"
2023-06-13T06:34:22.0747643Z MIXMASTER="mixmaster"
2023-06-13T06:34:22.0747771Z 
2023-06-13T06:34:22.0748027Z To contact the developers, please mail to <mutt-dev@mutt.org>.
2023-06-13T06:34:22.0748255Z To report a bug, please contact the Mutt maintainers via gitlab:
2023-06-13T06:34:22.0748463Z     https://gitlab.com/muttmua/mutt/issues
2023-06-13T06:34:22.0748544Z 
2023-06-13T06:34:22.2419708Z ##[section]Finishing: Email with E2E
```

report and logs using utils

What could be the reason? Set up is on Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not sending an email with mutt in that example of yours, you're running `mutt -v` (which displays mutt's version and compilation details), and then you're running `echo`.

If you want to send a message with mutt, you'd do it something like this:

```
mutt -s "subject" recipient@example.com <<__EOF__
Hello All,

Please find inline as well as attached the elaborative test results which $(Agent.JobStatus) and generated

Regards
QA Team

Link to Azure DevOps Pipeline Build : $url

__EOF__
```

You could use `echo` or `printf` or whatever to pipe your message into `mutt`, but as there are multiple newlines embedded in your msg, it's easier to use a heredoc.

See `man mutt` for more details on mutt command line options - e.g. you can use `-a filename` to attach a file using MIME, `-i filename` to include a file in the body of the message, `-c` for CC, and `-b` for BCC.

Comment: Thank you. This was helpful to resolve it. However I set the pipeline to execute after every hour. It runs successfully without any failures or error messages but the email is sent sporadically. It will send it once and then not for another couple of hours and then again send one more time. How do I make it send the email consistently.